# Analyze core dump from CentOS using convenient IDE like QtCreator or Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, gdbserver

I have a program written in C++. It's built on my dev machine with Ubuntu, and also on dev CentOS. Then binary from dev CentOS runs on live server. Where it crashed and now I have core dump. I'm able to get the dump on my dev CentOS and examine it using GDB. But it's complicated to use console on dev CentOS. I want to use QtCreator or Eclipse to examine the dump.
I think it's possible to do it using gdbserver, but I failed. Could you give me some advices?

Comment: Could you please explain, what does it mean - 'failed'? Using console on Linux should be essential skill for developer, so I don't understand why it is so complicated type command `bt` in gdb console.

Comment: What do you mean by "dump"? Have you tried sharing the relevant directory between machines? To this end, I would suggest using sshfs to make the CentOS data available to your Ubuntu applications.

Comment: dump = core dump, generated on live server when daemon crashed

Comment: "failed" - failed to use IDE to debug. Using gdb on dev CentOS, bt, bt full, etc is not a problem